# QR to pay more than one address?

Tags: transactions, qrcode

I know that I can generate syntax for a payment qr code like so:

`bitcoin:xxxaddressxxx?lable=reason&amount=0.051`

this pays (to) 1 address! I however, would like to know if I can scan a QR that will construct a tx that pays to two addresses

(can I add more than one address?)

eg:

`bitcoin:[xxxaddressxxx1,xxxaddressxxx2]?lable=reason&amount=[0.05,0.001]`

so the addresses receive amounts relative to the array positions

Comment: You would also need a wallet that can read a QR code that has this info encoded, and generate a 'send to many' transaction. I'm not aware of any wallets that have this functionality, but I don't see why it couldn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

As per [BIP 21](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0021.mediawiki), Bitcoin URIs are only allowed to contain a single address.

You are free to develop your own format that supports multiple outputs, but it won't get very far unless you can convince other wallets to adopt it.